# Using Entity Framework, how can I add a foreign key on two models to reference each other

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity

I have a ASP.NET MVC 5/C# project. In my project I have two models, `Rule` and `MenuItem`. `MenuItem` has a foreign key that references `Rule`. And `Rule` has a foreign key that references `MenuItem`.

Couple things worth mentioning, my model have a Prefix in the model name. Also, I am using database first approach.

I want to be able to get the MenuItem with the required rule using `.Include(...)` and also I want to be able to get the Rules with the MenuItem

Here are my models

```
[Table("Rules")]
public class PrefixRule
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Item")]
    public int ModuleId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual PrefixMenuItem Item { get; set; }
}

[Table("MenuItems")]
public class PrefixMenuItem
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("RequiredRule")]
    public int? RequiredRuleId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual PrefixRule RequiredRule { get; set; }
}
```

However, when I try to pull the menu-items including the required-rule, I get the following error

> One or more validation errors were detected during model
>   generation:MenuItem_RequiredRule_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid
>   in Role 'MenuItem_RequiredRule_Target' in relationship
>   'MenuItem_RequiredRule'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not
>   the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the
>   Dependent Role must be '*'.

I believe this error due to the circular references between my models. However, I need to be able to access both properties either way.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Where are your primary keys in your entities? `Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties`

Comment: Ehm a bit off topic but I suggest you use Guids in stead of ints for ID's. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.newguid(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework should be smart enough to figure out that this is 1 to 0/1 relationship. Not tested but this should work?

```
public partial class Rule
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Item")]
    public string ModuleId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual MenuItem Item { get; set; }
}

public partial class MenuItem
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Rule RequiredRule { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: well it isn't as smart as you think it is. This is what I get `{"Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'Rule' and 'MenuItem'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations."}` Please remember that I am using a database first approach

Comment: Sorry, only one model should be the principal. This is tested. I edited.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going this route then you have to make public string Id in the both the Primary and Foreign Key in your Rules table by decorating it with  [Key, ForeignKey("PrefixMenuItem")]

See this article for a full example: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Updated Example:

```
public partial class Rule
{

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key, ForeignKey("Item")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Module")]
    public int ModuleId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual MenuItem Item { get; set; }
    public virtual Module Module { get; set; }
}

public partial class MenuItem
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual Rule RequiredRule { get; set; }
}

public partial class Module
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ModuleId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: I get this error `{"Unable to determine composite primary key ordering for type 'MenuItem'. Use the ColumnAttribute (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386388) or the HasKey method (see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=386387) to specify an order for composite primary keys."}`  I already have a `Key` in both of my models which is `Id`

Comment: Did you try to remedy it following the recommendation? Adding the column order decoration to items that have your keys? [Column(Order = 0)]

Comment: Well, hold up, where is your ModuleId on your MenuItem class. It looks like your telling it to navigate to there to find it by that foreign key naming convention. Updating my answer to show a mock class that will hopefully help.

Comment: You actually don't even need the column ordering in that event bc the only reason you would in this case is if both FK pointed at the same table